# How to get Car_type, Marks and model in controller Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How to get results based on the selected fields. if car_type was selected to get a car, if audi was selected to get only models for audi. Example user select car_type Car , get Marks, user select Mark Audi got A1,A2. User select BMW got X6, X5.
I connect all only need to recieve data from database. Look my code.

Car_type table:

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
```

Marks table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->timestamps();
$table->integer('car_type_id');
```

Models table:

```
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('mark_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('car_type_id');
```

Car_type Model:

```
public function marks(){
    return $this->hasMany(Mark::class);
}
```

Mark model:

```
public function car_type(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Car_type::class);
}
public function carmodels(){
    return $this->hasMany(CarModel::class);
}
```

CarModel model:

```
public function mark(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Mark::class);
}
```

Now I need get data in controller. I try this

```
$car_type = Car_type::where('id' , $id)->first();
return $car_type->marks()->get();
```

Get marks with id of car_type model 1 but this is bad logic.

Comment: *but this is bad logic.* Why? You could write up a query that does all of it in one go, but what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take the car marks directly to do a single query instead of 2.

```
return Mark::where('car_type_id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: Okey  but how get models? 
And did I need id in parameter of my function? 
I am little confused. 
When I testing in postman i set baseUrl/marks/1 
Why 1 i don't know

Comment: This question is really vague. What do you mean by "why 1?". Your route is defined like `/marks/{id}` where id is the mark id you want to get the models for. That being said you can use that ID parameter in your controller method as an argument.

Comment: Okey, how I can get models for selected mark? @metei

Comment: It would be in another function like a getModels which have a parameter id ? :)

Comment: Not necessarily. When you have the `Mark` object you can access the relationships of it and you get the models directly. Like I just wrote to you before. You can do another method if the situation requests it..

Comment: I don't know how do it in same function.
I try this but this is very bad logic. I create new function with new route...very bad
I don't know how to id in same function?

    public function getModels($id){
        $models = CarModel::where('mark_id', $id)
            ->select('name')
            ->get();

        return $models;
    }

Comment: Try to update your question as it is very very hard to understand what you actually looking for.

Comment: when i try $marl->carmodels i get 

Property [carmodels] does not exist on this collection instance.

I only need when user select Marks to get models for that marks. 
When Select audi to get a3,a4,a5 models.
How to explane better ? :D

Comment: That's because you selected multiple marks. So the method returns a collection of marks not a single mark. What you should do is `foreach ($marks as $mark) { var_dump($mark->carmodels); }`

Comment: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[501]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)

Comment: items is empty array